# How do I speed up my MySQL query that gets an AVG of most recent transaction per user?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm pretty sure my implementation for this solution is the least efficient (takes 2 seconds to complete when run over only 30,000 records). Is there a faster way?

My MySQL query, followed by explanation below:

```
SELECT  DATE(m.date) AS day,
        AVG(t.amount) AS amount
FROM    transactions s

            LEFT JOIN users m
                ON m.id = s.user_id
WHERE   
        #only consider the most recent transaction for each user
        s.id = (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    transactions s2
        WHERE   s2.user_id = s.user_id
                AND s2.created_date = (
                    SELECT  MAX(created_date)
                    FROM    transactions s3
                    WHERE   s3.user_id = s.user_id
                )
        )
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```

Basically it's saying "show the average transaction amount per day, considering only each user's most recent transaction".

I've already created an index on created_date.

I don't want to just select the MAX(transaction.id) for user related transactions, because there's no guarantee that new transaction records added to the table are always for newer real world transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Three selects looks like too many.

```
SELECT t.date, avg(t.amount) 
FROM transactions t
JOIN 
  (SELECT user_id, max(created_date) AS max_date 
   FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id) AS t2
ON t.user_id=t2.user_id and t.created_date=max_date
GROUP BY t.date
ORDER BY t.date;
```

Note this includes *all* transactions by a given user on the most recent day he had any transactions. There doesn't seem to be a timestamp.

Make sure there is a composite index on `user_id, created_date`.